# react-timezone достать цифры таймзоны

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Доброго времени суток, я начинающий, в проекте используется "react-timezone",
в форме

```
                     <TimezonePicker
                        value={this.props.timezone}
                        placeholder="Greenwich Mean Time"
                        className="col-12"
                        style={{width: "100%"}}
                        onChange={this.onChangeTimezone}
                        inputProps={{
                           placeholder: 'Select Timezone...',
                           name: 'timezone',
                           id: 'timezone'
                        }}
                    />

onChangeTimezone(value: string) {
    let val = moment().tz(value).format('Z');
    this.props.onChangeTimezone(value);
    this.props.onChangeForm && this.props.onChangeForm({timezone});
}
```

По хорошему, в react-timezone передавать цифры, он это может? Как?

Comment: Более точнее о проблеме - при submite отпвлялись цифры и плохо работала связка react-timezone и moment, часовой пояс из react-timezone и moment не совпадали.

Comment: Отказались от react-timezones, использовали react-widgets и таймзоны из moment-timezones
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991113/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-available-timezone-using-moment-timezone